# Make bootstrap popover work with custom html template

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using an input group textbox and I need the Bootstrap 3 popover to work and the popover template should be defined &n designed by me.
So the html I have currently with me is :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control jq-timePicker" value="09:30">
                <span class="input-group-addon" rel="popover">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want a popover to open when the input group icon is click. In this case when the span with class glyphicon-time is clicked a popover is or displayed with the following HTML:

```
<div class="timePickerWrapper popover">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="popover-content">
                <div class="timePickerCanvas"></div>
                <div class="timePickerClock timePickerHours"></div>
                <div class="timePickerClock timePickerMinutes"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS written:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var popoverTemplate = ['<div class="timePickerWrapper popover">',
        '<div class="arrow"></div>',
        '<div class="popover-content">',
        '<div class="timePickerCanvas"></div>',
        '<div class="timePickerClock timePickerHours"></div>',
        '<div class="timePickerClock timePickerMinutes"></div>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>'].join('');


    $('body').popover({
        selector: '[rel=popover]',
        trigger: 'click',
        template: popoverTemplate,
        placement: "bottom",
        html: true
    });
});
```

See the fiddle here: http://www.bootply.com/4fMzxGRpik

Can anyone please help me correcting what mistake I am doing and what needs to be done to display a popvhover.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you are missing the content of the popover, you'll need something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var popoverTemplate = ['<div class="timePickerWrapper popover">',
        '<div class="arrow"></div>',
        '<div class="popover-content">',
        '</div>',
        '</div>'].join('');

    var content = ['<div class="timePickerCanvas">asfaf asfsadf</div>',
        '<div class="timePickerClock timePickerHours">asdf asdfasf</div>',
        '<div class="timePickerClock timePickerMinutes"> asfa </div>', ].join('');


    $('body').popover({
        selector: '[rel=popover]',
        trigger: 'click',
        content: content,
        template: popoverTemplate,
        placement: "bottom",
        html: true
    });
});
```

[Working demo](http://www.bootply.com/ICbHgauH3Y)

Comment: Docs are unobvious about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would prefer to have all the HTML in templates. It goes like this:

Something in Javascript

```
$(".btn").popover({
   template: $("#selector").html(),
   placement: "auto"
});
```

And in HTML

```
<div id="selector">
    Anything you want in your popovers, either dynamic or static
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@code-jaff that is a great answer, but i noticed that the Working Demo's popover doesn't look like it's coming out of the button. If this is happening to anyone else, try adding container: 'body' to the popover options. Like this:

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '[rel=popover]',
    trigger: 'click',
    content: content,
    template: popoverTemplate,
    placement: "bottom",
    html: true,
    container: 'body'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I want to try is a minimal configuration and don't want to split code into JS and HTML, And here is my solution.

Here what I found,

Bootstrap Version 4.5.2
Added popper js

Put your code in the data-content attribute.

Here is my HTML code

```
<a tabindex="0" html="true" class="btn btn-sm" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And heres some <b>amazing content</b>. Its very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Here is my JS code

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html : true
 });
```